# css image from hard disk

Tags: css, image, load, workspace

im about to build a GUI and I am trying to load an image as background image via css. 
My HTML sheet is nearly empty except the headline and a div container in which I load the GUI, built with JAVA and the Google Web Toolkit.

Loading the background image from the internet works out pretty well!

```
.Bild {
    background: url("http://developer.aldebaran-robotics.com/media/img/home/nao_h25.png")
    no-repeat
    center;
}
```

BUT now i want to load it from my hard disk, better to say from a folder in the project. 
The structure looks like this:

workspace → project → war → css file

workspace
→ project
→ images
→ image.png

I tried it by using a relative path. I am not sure if I did it correctly. It doesnt work:

```
.Bild {
    background: url(/images/image.png)
    no-repeat
    center;
}
```

Im sure you can help me!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to avoid starting class- and ID-names with a capital letter in CSS. What do these return in your console; `window.location.domain` and `window.location.href`?

Comment: console says file not found for "images/image.png"

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the path of the image file relative to the css file
Lets take your directory structure example:

```
workspace/
 project/
   war/
      cssfile.css
   images/
      image.png
```

Your image path relative to the css file would have to be

> ```
> ../images/image.png
> ```

```
.Bild {
    background: url(../images/image.png)
    no-repeat
    center;
}
```

Here: `..` means one directory above the current directory. You can use `../../` to go two directories up.

To figure out the relative path, you need to navigate up to the common parent directory and then walk down to the location of the media file. In this case, the common parent directory is one level up, hence `../` is enough and then walk down the directory structure `images/image.png`.

Comment: how far do I need to go back in the structure? waht does ".." mean..?!

Comment: `..` means one directory above the current directory. You can use `../../` to go two directories up

Comment: this is the whole path: D:\Users\MyName\Documents\UNI\SWT\Praktikum\workspace\NaoRemoteControl\images\im‌​age.png

Comment: D:\Users\MyName\Documents\UNI\SWT\Praktikum\workspace\NaoRemoteControl\war\file.css

Comment: Can you try this: `background: #ffffff url('../images/image.png') no-repeat center top;` (with the quote)

Comment: sorry for asking... im pretty sure im no idiot but i dont get it why you always write ../ if i got your edit right, i only have to go back to images which means the relative path is (images/image.png)...

Comment: You have to traverse relative to the current file you are referencing it from. If you do not specify the `../`, the css interpreter will look for a folder named `images` within the current directory, which is `war/` which it would not find. However `../images/image.png` implies go 1 directory above `war/` and then look for a file named `image.png` within a directory called `images`

Comment: i tried: .bild {
 background: #ffffff url(images/image.png) no-repeat center top;
}  didnt work. (/images/image.png) neither but (http://...) was fine!

Comment: Just see the explanation I gave in the comment above. This wont work. Also, you are using `.bild` and in the question `.Bild` class names are case sensitive

Comment: i changed it after recognizing that capital letters are not common for css ids. sorry. thats all good. the path isnt right. (/images.image.png) didnt work... like nearly all combinations i tried...

Comment: I still dont understand why you are against trying `../images/image.png` . Just copy and paste this , and see if it does not work

Comment: so i guess you cant help me?

Comment: Do you have a dev environment where you can share the url? I can take a look

Comment: what do u exactly need? see my code or see my gui so u can imagine what im trying to do with the inmage!?

Comment: Ok.. lets go back to basics: 1) Is there a file named image.png in the images/ directory? 2) ifyou do a viewsource, or if you try and access the png file from your browser, can you access it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the syntax. So the problem must be with the path. 
By starting the url with a slash `/`,

```
/images/image.png
```

implies an absolute location of

```
http://some-host-name/images/image.png
```

is that where your image is?

Comment: the complete path is this: D:\Users\MyName\Documents\UNI\SWT\Praktikum\workspace\NaoRemoteControl\images\image.png

Comment: Is the \NaoRemoteControl\ folder the root directory for the web site? If so, your path should work. If not, create a sym-link (you are on a unix or linux machine, no?) to your images folder just inside whatever directory *is* your web-site's root directory.

Comment: what do you mean by "directory for the website"? i have a workspace where my project (NaoRemoteControl) is stored. this project includes 2 folders: "images"-where the image is stored ane "war" where the css fil is. if I understood everything correctly, the relative path is /images/image.png so I would be : .bild {
 background: url(../images/abc.png) no-repeat center top;
}

Comment: Are you hosting on an Apache server? Then the directory is called DocumentRoot and can be found/edited in the httpd.conf file. Try to just bring that image up in your browser using your hostname (localhost if in dev, usually, or mydomain.net) and the path, so, e.g. `http://localhost/images/abc.png`. If you can't then that's part of your problem -- you need to be sure you understand the location of the file with respect to http and the web, not just your local directory structure.

Comment: ... ah, pardon me, I see you have already successfully loaded the image from the web using "http://developer.aldebaran-robotics.com/media/img/home/nao_h25.png" -- then you *should* be able to reference the file with "/media/img/home/nao_h25.png" -- note the beginning slash -- regardless of where your stylesheet is located.