# How do I use a local file as a background image with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Before you ask, yes, I have put the image I want to set as the background in the same folder as the the CSS document.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/16jlavarnway/Desktop/blah/JacobLFinalCSS.css"/>
        <title>Programming with Python</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS

```
body {
    background-image:url:("C:/Users/16jlavarnway/Desktop/blah/Background2.png") fixed center;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax for the `background-image` is wrong. No colon after "url"

Comment: If you're on a server, use the server path.

Comment: even without the colon, still deosnt work

Comment: Yep! and try relative url instead of full path. 
Another think, I thing full path should be write like that `file:///C:\`

Comment: `background-image:url("file://Users/16jlavarnway/Desktop/blah/Background2.png") fixed center;`

Comment: jsut trying to add a single image for the background for my final. no servers, no complicated stuff, just html and css.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744919/css-image-from-hard-disk

Comment: @melanchiaUK nope, still no good, just a black white page Edit: regarding your first post

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use relative path. Also, it would be good to read about CSS before venturing around it.

Comment: I'm taking it cadeacademy doesnt count as a valid place to learn CSS?

Comment: Inspect the element in your browser console, look for the CSS rule and hover the mouse over the image link. If it's invalid (not found) you'll know it.

Answer (score 10):

This should be the correct syntax

```
body {
    background-image:url("C:/Users/16jlavarnway/Desktop/blah/Background2.png") fixed center;
}
```

Besides, if you have your site hosted online, your image route should be

```
body {
        background-image:url("Background2.png") fixed center;
    }
```

The same with the HTML, you will have to change the route.

Answer (score 3):

```
background-image:url:("C:/Users/16jlavarnway/Desktop/blah/Background2.png");
```

Would be changed to

```
background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/16jlavarnway/Desktop/blah/Background2.png");
```

You were having an extra `:` in the URL. Now it would work! :) Second thing is you're referring to the File System. You need to write `File:///` to create the URI.

**Note**: Just make sure, the image is present at that location.

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 3):

```
background-image:url("../Background2.png")
```

if server you will need to add the correct assets whereever your inetpub will be placed (if localhost)

Comment: why was this downvoted for an answer considering we dont even know how he's hosting it?